# A romance manga about a girl going deaf in her right ear

Tags: identification-request

I've been looking for this manga for ages and I don't know what it's called. It's a romance manga, and I think it's also of school life genre and is a one-shot.

All I remember is that it's about a girl and boy who share the same headphones to listen to music. She always listened with her right ear. But then one day, she woke up to find that her right ear had gone deaf. She tried to keep it a secret, but the boy accidentally put on really loud music, and because she couldn't hear, she wasn't surprised or anything, and that was where he realized.

One day, the girl went to her part time job in a shop and someone placed their order. Because she couldn't hear clearly, she asked him to repeat the order, so the customer got angry. At that moment, the boy stepped in and explained the situation. After that, he confronted the girl about why she didn't tell him about her condition.

I think it was a pretty modern art style. I read it about one and a half to two years ago

I don't remember how it ended but I would love to read the manga again to find out.

Comment: When did you read it? How is the art style? (Modern? '90s?) One-shot are much harder to find than a series, since they are usually short and don't leave much memory compared to a long series.

Answer (score 6):

It should be "**Kieta Hanbun, Nokotta Real**" (Half Gone, Love Remains) oneshot from "Kiss to Koukai" by **Mio Nanao**.

> A broken school festival sign and a common love for music makes best
>   buds out of Naru and Yamato. That is until Naru loses all hearing in
>   her right ear and she keeps her condition from Yamato a secret...